# Calculating value of $\delta$ for a function $y=\frac1{(1-x)^2}$ unbounded at $x\rightarrow 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

The function $y=\frac 1{(1-x)^2}$ is unbounded at $x\rightarrow 1$.

How can I calculate the value of $\delta$ such that $y> 10^6$ if $\left | x-1 \right |< \delta$ ?

Taking $y=f(x)=10^6$, putting in ${y=\frac1{(1-x)^2}}$, we get
$10^6 = \frac1{(1-x)^2}\\
\frac1{(1-x)^2} = \frac1{10^6}\\
x=1-\sqrt{(10^{-6})}$ meaning $x= 0.999$.

As, $\left |x-1\right |< \delta,$ hence $ \left|0.999 -1\right| < \delta,$ or
$10^{-3} < \delta$.

It can imply that,
$ \delta$ must be at least $10^{-3}$ or greater $ \delta \geq 10^{-3}$

(After correction by user:505767)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour.  You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context by stating what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959 .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You should show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Well done the editing with all the details!

Comment: I apologize as I'm new to this site.

Comment: @SalzEngineering That's fine! You have asked a good question. Keep the same standard for future questions. Note also that you can navigate the site to find similar and related questions form which you can learn a lot.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! <> You might double-check your square root of $10^{-6}$....

Answer (score 1):

Pick $\delta$ such that
$$y=\frac{1}{\delta^2}=10^6$$
then at $\delta=±0.001$, $y=10^6$.

So$$|x-1|<\delta=0.001$$
in order to have $$y=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}>\frac{1}{\delta^2}=10^6$$

Answer (score 0):

We have that for $A,B>0$ (i.e. dividing both sides by $AB$)

$$A>B \iff \frac 1 A < \frac 1 B$$

therefore

$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}>10^6 \iff (1-x)^2<\frac1{10^6}=10^{-6}$$

form which, using that $\sqrt{A^2}=|A|$ and (taking the square roots both sides)

$$A^2<B \iff |A|<\sqrt B$$

we find

$$(1-x)^2<10^{-6} \iff |1-x|<10^{-3}$$

and $|1-x|=|x-1|$.

In your evaluation it should be

$$x=1-\sqrt{10^{-6}}=1-10^{-3}=0.999$$

which is correct but not much effective and clear to obtain the result.